# how to add ubuntu router's network to a wireless router to expand its network

Tags: networking, wireless, server, internet, router

I have configured an ubuntu server to become a outer with dhcp functionalities and I saw this post on connecting one router to another to expand its network. My ubuntu router is on a vmware and I was wondering how do you add this to another router so the network may expand?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the capabilities of your wireless router, you might be able to configure it as a switch, thus extending your LAN that way.
On my LAN my main Ubuntu server is the router / dhcp server / firewall. My wireless router is configured as a switch, taking care of all the wireless requirements, while the devices themselves get their IP address from main DHCP server, and everything is on one sub-net. So that I can still connect to the administration web interface of the wireless router (switch), it has a static IP address on the same local sub-net, but outside of the pool of addresses reserved for dynamic allocation.
So, I have:

WAN <--> Ubuntu Server <--> switch <--> wireless router configured as a switch